# Laravel 5.5 scopes definition

Tags: laravel-5, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I'm trying to make a scopes configuration. The scopes are build in the follow schema:

```
module:submodule:action
```

Also, I defined on boot section

```
Passport::tokensCan($scopes);
```

However, I got the following error when I'm trying to generate a token using oauth2 with Passport:

```
The requested scope is invalid, unknown, or malformed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was method tokensCan receive an array, the keys must be the scopes for evaluate later with middleware scope or scopes.

```
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
Passport::tokensCan([
    'place-orders' => 'Place orders',
    'check-status' => 'Check order status',
]);
```

Comment: Nice, I just had the same error and your solution helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A good tip is go to `app\Providers\AuthServiceProvider`
In the method `boot` add the follows code:

```php
    public function boot()
    {
        // ...

        Passport::routes();
        Passport::tokensCan([
            'place-orders' => 'Place orders',
            'check-status' => 'Check order status',
        ]);
    }
```

It's work for me. (:

Answer (score 0):

You may define your API's scopes using the `Passport::tokensCan` method in the boot method of your `application's App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider` class. The tokensCan method accepts an array of scope names and scope descriptions. The scope description may be anything you wish and will be displayed to users on the authorization approval screen:

```
public function boot(): void
{
    Passport::tokensCan([
        'place-orders' => 'Place orders',
        'check-status' => 'Check order status',
    ]);
}
```